# Replace a string with another that contains newlines

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say I have:

```
template=$(<template.txt)
replacement=$(<replacement.txt)
```

How do I then store in a third variable the value of `template`, with "REPLACE_ME" replaced with the content of `replacement`, no matter what `template` and `replacement` contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with GNU bash 4:

```
foo="${template//REPLACE_ME/$replacement}"
```